# Qestion about understanding "detach()" on threads in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I always saw in the internet the rule:

> If you don't detach\join a thread, then abort will be called.

I need a reason for why that abort happens.

I can understand with join — because when not doing join to some thread, the the main can be closed before the thread and it can make problems.

But detach doesn't do anything! It has no purpose (at least from what I've seen when running a thread with or without being detached).

What exactly make the abort to jump, any what exactly is the purpose of detach?

Here is a simple example for what causing "aborting":

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <thread>         // std::thread, std::this_thread::sleep_for
#include <chrono>         // std::chrono::seconds

void pause_thread(int n) 
{
  std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(n));
  std::cout << "pause of " << n << " seconds ended\n";
}

int main() 
{
  std::cout << "Spawning and detaching 3 threads...\n";
  std::thread (pause_thread,1);
  std::cout << "Done spawning threads.\n";
  // give the detached threads time to finish (but not guaranteed!):
  pause_thread(5);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How come that `detach` doesn't do anything?! Imagine that when the main thread spawns another thread, the latter becomes sorta its slave, dependent on its parent. When you `detach` the child thread, it breaks free and _lives its own life_.

Comment: @ForceBru How do you see that reflecting within a program? everybody who explain me that, tell me the same thing. that the thread is "getting free!!!" but what does it mean?????

Comment: it means that this thread is now independent from any other threads: if its parent thread is terminated, it continues running, while the 'slave' thread will have to commit suicide in this case.

Comment: A couple of related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19744250/440558 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/6042970/440558. A quick search should give you many more.

Answer (score 0):

A thread is a different beast from a process. Threads are **not** in a parent/child relation at all.

C++11 thread implementation has to be compatible with all major OS threads, so it had to make design decisions, which cannot be understood at first sight.

I'll describe pthread, which is used in the linux world.

When you create a thread, you can specify its detachstate. It can be two values:

- DETACHED: when the thread exits, its allocated resources automatically released. Thread **cannot** be joined.
- JOINABLE: when the thread exits, some of its resources are not automatically freed. For example, its return code (in pthread, there is a return value of a thread). Thread **can** be joined. Resources will be freed at `join()`.

C++ threads are created as JOINABLE, but you can detach it later.

Now, if you don't detach/join a thread, at `~thread()`, what could a thread implementation do? It is an issue, because if it doesn't do anything, then some resource will be silently leaked (as a JOINABLE thread when exits, some of its resources are not automatically freed)

- call `join()` automatically: not a good idea, as the program can stall on it (if the thread still runs). It is potentially a programming bug.
- call `detach()` automatically: not a good idea either, as it could be a programming bug (thread **continue** to run, but its `thread` object is destroyed -  a programmer should explicitly call `detach()` in this case)
- call `abort()`: this is the best that an implementation can do, to avoid programming errors

So the designers of `std::thread` chose to call `abort()` to avoid programming errors.

(On windows, the thread system is similar. You have to call `CloseHandle` for a thread so its resources can be released)